# Determining if System is consistent based on Null Space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose $A$ is a $4\times 5$ matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^4$. Decide
>   whether the system $Ax = b$ is consistent if
>   $\dim(\operatorname{Null}(A)) = \dim (\operatorname{Null} [A|b]) = 4$

---

My question has two parts. The first is this $\dim (\operatorname{Null} [A|b])$.

I know it would look like this (using $2\times2$ for simplicity): $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} && a_{12} & | & b_1\\a_{21} && a_{22} & | & b_2\end{bmatrix}$

How do I deal with things like Rank, Row Space, Null Space, etc in this kind of matrix (also, does it have a special name I can use)? Can I simply ignore the 'line' and treat it exactly as I would a normal matrix, or are there some special properties that I need to be aware of?

---

Assuming that I can treat it as a regular matrix, then I am just doing it like this;

If $\dim(\operatorname{Null}(A)) = \dim (\operatorname{Null} [A|b]) = 4$ then $Rk(A) = 1$ and $Rk(A|b) = 2$. This means $b$ has a non-zero entry in a zero-row of $A$ (in RREF), and therefore the system is NOT consistent.

Is that answer both correct, and sufficiently explanatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right: we have $rank(A|b) \ne rank(A)$ and therefore the system $Ax=b$ has no solution.

Comment: So $A|b$ is just a normal matrix?

Comment: Yes. $A|b$ has the columns of $A$ and the one additional column $b$.

Comment: Easy. Thank you very much for your help :)